# scaling/formatting multiple imagebutton array in Android

Tags: android, xml, image, layout

So I have this task to create a horizontal scrolling array of image buttons that are basically photo avatars of users.  These avatars aren't constrained by aspect ratio or size, and so I've been playing with ways to scale them and format them.  I've gotten them scaling via the scaletype="fitCenter" and using static width and height. But what I really want them to do is to butt up against one another.  Currently if an image is taller than it is high, you get the kind of letterboxing but on the sides vs. the top (blank areas).  I've tried all the different scaling values, wrapping each imagemap within a linearlayout, etc., but nothing I try seems to get rid of those (while displaying the entire image to scale).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Also, there's the top/bottom letterboxing for ones that are wider than they are tall.  My static width and height are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to reiterate what I think you're doing, you have three image scenarios:

1. Square image
2. Landscape image (wider than tall)
3. Portrait image (taller than wide)

Laying out a row of fixed-size ImageViews (or ImageButtons) using FIT_CENTER works great for what you need if all the images were either square or landscape, because the scaling will always make the image stretch to the horizontal bounds of the view (the largest dimension).  However, with portrait images, the scaling causes the view to be inside the bounds of your fixed-size view so that the entire image height can be visible.

If you need to maintain the aspect ratio of the image, there really is no ScaleType to help with this because the logic would be circular (fit the view to the image, while simultaneously fitting the image to the view).  The solution is to adjust the size (specifically, the width) of each ImageView to match what the image will be scaled to.  Here's a sample of a factory method you might use to generate the ImageView to fit the image you want to put inside it.  You could also modify this slightly to reset parameters on an existing ImageView if you like:

```
private ImageView getImageViewForThumbnail(Bitmap thumbnail) {
    float viewHeight = //Your chosen fixed view height
    float scale = ((float)thumbnail.getHeight()) / viewHeight;
    float viewWidth = thumbnail.getHeight() / scale;

    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)viewWidth, (int)viewHeight);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

    return view;
}
```

You're basically just calculating what the aspect width of the ImageView should be to match the fixed height you've chosen for all of them.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this would be the only real way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scaleType `fitXY`, it stretches the image to the layout params you assigned, if the image has less dimensions and also shrinks the image to the layout params you assigned, if the image is large. The key point is to mention the image layout params to the imageView , that is the width and height of the image.

Comment: Ok, I tried fitXY but it doesn't scale the image properly.  The thing is that I'm putting in static values for the image dimensions (or the linearlayout that surrounds it.  I guess my question is, is there any way to scale these images without added space on the right or left (for portrait pictures) or top and bottom (for landscape pictures) but without knowing what the image dimensions will be beforehand? Will we need to write some code that looks at the image properties and then calculates an appropriate width so that the scale is correct?

Comment: I think you should try with assigning static values to imageView, according to documentation, "fitXY" should work if you want the image to scale in x and y independently. check these two links. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html which uses FILL described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#FILL